# passing callback function to a plugin which should remember it's environment

Tags: javascript

I am using a plugin which accepts a callback function like

```
function periodicRequests( container ) {
    var options = {
                url: "/?dummy-ajax-url",
                interval: 1000,
                ..
                onReady: _callback
            }
  _pluingcall( options );

}
function _callback() {
 .....
 ....
 return params&for&ajax&call
}
```

Now I am interested in that the `_callback` function should have access to `container` element which is defined in `periodicRequests` function
I have tried something like

```
var options = {
    url: "/?dummy-ajax-url",
    interval: 1000,
    // ...
    onReady: function(container) {
        return function() {
            return _callback(container);
        }
    }(container)
}
```

Is it OK so or I can simplify this?

Comment: Use bind instead. `_callback.bind(this, container)`

Answer (score 1):

## May this will help

```
function periodicRequests( container ) {
var options = {
            url: "/?dummy-ajax-url",
            interval: 1000,
            ..
            onReady: function(){
               //can access container here too
            }
        }
_pluingcall( options );

}
```